# Is 'dwc2' limited to USB direct connections?

Tags: usb, headless, ethernet-port, config.txt, cmdline.txt

The [instructions](https://gist.github.com/gbaman/975e2db164b3ca2b51ae11e45e8fd40a) for setting up a direct-connect RPi Zero over USB have me

- add `dtoverlay=dwc2` on a new line to `config.txt', and
- insert `modules-load=dwc2,...` in `cmdline.txt`.

Are these settings specific to or limited to the RPi Zero and/or to a direct USB connection? That is, could I use an SD card with these settings generally on on my RPi's regardless of how I connect to them. For example, could I use these settings without side effects on an RPi 2 or 3 that I connect to using the Ethernet port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use those settings on all my SD cards and swap those cards merrily between Pi Zero, Pi B+ and Pi 2 with no side effects.

Comment: All the linked-to settings, or just the `dwc2` settings above?

Comment: The link in the OP only outlines these 2 settings, as I read it..? 
Which other settings are you concerned about ?

Comment: Yes, the OP (me) just asked about those, I wanted to confirm that "those" didn't refer to the link as well.

Comment: Ah - I think I get it - all OTG settings you mean ?   I set dtoverlay=dwc2 and modules-load=dwc2,g_ether only